# Nodejs not connecting to MongoDB running in Sandbox

Tags: node.js

So , I have started to learn Mean Stack and I am facing this issue when trying to connect to mongodb running in sandbox, my antivirus is disabled

This is my code,

```
            const express = require("express");
            const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
            const Post = require("./models/post");
            const mongoose = require("mongoose");

            const app = express();

            mongoose
            .connect(
                "mongodb+srv://bharat:<password>@mongodbcluster-rkdrm.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
                { useNewUrlParser: true }
            )
            .then(() => {
                console.log("Connected to DB");
            })
            .catch(() => {
                console.log("Connection failed!");
            });

            app.use(bodyParser.json());
            app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

            app.use((req, res, next) => {
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            res.setHeader(
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
            );
            res.setHeader(
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
            );
            next();
            });

            app.post("/api/posts", (req, res, next) => {
            const post = new Post({
                title: req.body.title,
                content: req.body.content
            });

            console.log(post);
            res.status(201).json({
                message: "Post added successfully"
            });
            });

            app.get("/api/posts", (req, res, next) => {
            const posts = [
                {
                id: "fadf12421l",
                title: "First server-side post",
                content: "This is coming from the server"
                },
                {
                id: "ksajflaj132",
                title: "Second server-side post",
                content: "This is coming from the server!"
                }
            ];
            res.status(200).json({
                message: "Posts fetched successfully!",
                posts: posts
            });
            });

            module.exports = app;
```

Any ideas ? I know it can be done easily with downloading mongodb in my local, but I thought running in cloud will make me learn something.

Also when trying to connect using the windows powershell, I get the output as below

```
            PS C:\Users\BHARAT> Test-NetConnection -InformationLevel detailed -ComputerName portquiz.net -Port 27017


            ComputerName            : portquiz.net
            RemoteAddress           : 52.47.209.216
            RemotePort              : 27017
            NameResolutionResults   : 52.47.209.216
            MatchingIPsecRules      :
            NetworkIsolationContext : Internet
            IsAdmin                 : False
            InterfaceAlias          : Wi-Fi
            SourceAddress           : 10.159.134.2
            NetRoute (NextHop)      : 10.159.0.1
            TcpTestSucceeded        : True
```

Comment: Check the access to cloud use replica set. And what service are you using? Mongodb Atlas?

Comment: yup atlas, it says I have access to use replica set

Comment: Can you print the error message?

Comment: { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongodbcluster-shard-00-02-rkdrm.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to mongodbcluster-shard-00-02-rkdrm.mongodb.net:27017 closed]

Comment: Connection closed there are a problem on your mongo db atlas,

Comment: I deleted the cluster and created new and it worked

Comment: Then please answer your question by yourself and accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I terminated the cluster and for good measure I updated my IP address and worked fine.